# Is it syntactically correct to write "This and the following pages"?

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis

... or is there a better alternative to writing something like "This and the following pages constitute a summary of topic X."?

Comment: I am unsure if it is syntactically wrong, but simpler would be: "These pages constitute a summary of topic X."

Comment: Or "the topic is summarized in these pages".

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, that does indeed sound better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is syntactically well-formed, which isn't to say that it can't be made simpler in your  particular example with "constitute a summary".

> This and the following three episodes provide back-story.

We're talking about four episodes:

> This [episode] and the following three episodes provide back-story.

Comment: But is it really, though? If I were to write it out completely, the sentence would go "This episode and the following three episodes...", so isn't it wrong to contract a singular and plural of the same noun into one single plural of the noun?

Comment: I get it. "This and the following" is a similar phrase like "Greg and his friends": "Greg is reading, and his friends are reading". "Greg and his friends are reading."